# Does either condition of a topological group imply the other?

Tags: group-theory

A topological group is a group with a topology such that both product and inverse are continuous. Is there a case where product is continuous but not inverse, and also vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{R}_l$, the real numbers with lower limit topology, the topology with basis
$$\{[a,b):a<b\}, $$
then $+:\mathbb{R}_l\times\mathbb{R}_l\to \mathbb{R}_l$ is continuous but the inverse 
function $x\mapsto -x$ is not continuous.

Again consider $\mathbb{R}$ with cocountable topology, in which all sets with countable complement are open, then addition is discontinuous but $x\mapsto -x$ is continuous.